# Sketching a continuous path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, parametrization

> Given are the integration paths $\alpha, \beta, \gamma: [0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ and $ \delta : [0,3]\to\mathbb{C}$:
>   $$\begin{align*}
> \alpha(t)&=2,5e^{2\pi i t}\\
> \beta(t)&=-1,5i+1,5\cos(\pi(t+1))+0,5 i \sin(\pi(t+1)) \\
> \gamma(t)&=-1,5i+2it \\
> \\
> \delta(t)&= \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll} -1+0,5e^{i\pi(1/2-2t)} &, 0\leq t \leq 1\\
> -1+0,5i+2(t-1) &, 1\leq t\leq 2\\
> 1+0,5e^{i\pi(9/2-2t)} &, 2\leq t\leq 3 \end{array}\right.\\
> \end{align*} $$
>   Sketch the trace of the chain $\Gamma=\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta$ and compute $$\displaystyle \int_{\delta} z\, \mathrm{d}z$$.

First I want to make this equations easier:
$$
\beta(t)=-1,5i -1,5 e^{\frac{1}{3}i\pi t}\\
\gamma(t)= 2i\left(t-\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
Only for $\delta(t)$ I didn't get something useful.

Unfortunately I don't know how to sketch this. To find the starting and ending point of each path, maybe I have to calculate $\alpha(0), \alpha(1)$, etc. Is this the right way? Thank you!

Comment: Is this how the question is written?  What is with these expressions like "-1 + 0" and $\beta(t) =$ three parameters?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the question.

Comment: Four parameters, even^

What does $\alpha$ even look like?  I don't understand this notation at all.  Is it that $\alpha(t) = (2, e^{2 \pi it})$ in real coordinates?  Because that makes no sense.  What is the comma?

Comment: Ahhh sorry. Thats the european notation. The 'comma' is the point, e.g. 2,5 = 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Note that in the complex plane,

- path $\alpha$ is a circle centered at $0$ of radius $2.5$.
- path $\beta$ is a half of an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) centered at $-1.5i$, semi-major axis of $1.5$ and semi minor axis of $1.5$.
- path $\gamma$ is a segment from $-1.5i$ to $0.5i$.

Are you able to sketch the path $\delta$ now?

As regards the integral $\int_{\delta}z\,dz$, note that it suffices to find the endpoints of the path $\delta$ (why?).

Comment: Thank you! Do you really mean $\gamma$? Where do you get the $0.5i$?

Comment: Yes, $-1.5i+2i=0.5i$.